# Recoding in R for items with missing data

Tags: r, null, recode

I just started working with R and this is one of problems:
I want to recode text variables from one item (column) in numeric variables. Since I had missing values, I tried to recode like this:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library("dplyr")
zdf_all <- read.csv("Daten_einlesen.csv")
zdf2 <- read.csv("Daten_einlesen.csv", header=T, na.strings=c("","NA"))
zdf <- filter(zdf2, Status == "Complete")

names(zdf) [295] <- "pbc"
pbc = recode(zdf$value, 'Definitely agree'=5, 'Somewhat agree'=4, 'Neither agree or disagree'=3,'Somewhat disagree'=2, 'Definitely disagree'=1, 'NA'=0, as.factor.result=FALSE)
```

When I run the command I get this warning message:

```
  Error in UseMethod("recode") : 
  no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Why does it say I have an object of class of "NULL"? How can I recode my items succesfully?

I also tried the ifelse function which didn't work as well.

Comment: Could you share some details about how does the data frame `zdf` look? like output of `str(zdf)`

Comment: Why would you recode `NA` to `0` when converting a character scale to numeric?

Comment: @Taneja: do you mean this?
$ pbc                                               : Factor w/ 5 levels "Definitely agree",..: 3 1 5 1 5 3 4 2 3 3 ...

Comment: We need example data, please provide by `dput(zdf)` or `dput(head(zdf))` if it's too big.

Comment: @LAP: yes, this doesn't make sense, I recodes 'NA' to '0' in the second step, i thought it might could help

Comment: @jaySF: i have 637 variables (nominal, ordinal and metric), since this are very sensible data, can you tell me a common way to show here example data while respecting data protection?

Comment: Ok, in this case you may want to consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038)

Comment: @Papea, just `sample` from some columns and stitch them together to create a fictional dataframe. Example: `df <- data.frame(Status = sample(zdf2$Status, 10, replace = TRUE), value = sample(zdf2$value, 10, replace = TRUE))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
install.packages("car")
car::recode(zdf$pbc, "'Definitely agree'=5; 'Somewhat agree'=4; 'Neither agree nor disagree'=3; 'Somewhat disagree'=2; 'Definitely disagree'=1; 'NA'=0")
```

Comment: Thank so much, it worked! I just had to replace "," by ";". `car::recode(zdf$pbc, "'Definitely agree'=5; 'Somewhat agree'=4; 'Neither agree nor disagree'=3; 'Somewhat disagree'=2; 'Definitely disagree'=1; 'NA'=0")`